# Is it possible to connect Postgres database to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, connection, postgresql

I would like to connect my local PostgreSQL database to another MySQL database to update few tables (by trigger), but I don’t understand how to do it.

I know foreign data wrapper, but which extension should I to use on postgres side - `postgres_fdw` or `mysql_fdw` ? I haven’t found anywhere the answer.

Comment: Make sure you plan your error handling carefully! Given that you're pushing data between databases, I'd expect at some point that you're going to run into a situation where one DB is down while the other wants to talk to it - you need to make sure that doesn't kill your system.

Comment: I think fdw should to have timeout option for safety.

Comment: Sure, but that's the just mechanism. The important part is: What then? If the trigger to push data to the other DB fails, how is that going to affect the rest of your system? THAT's the hard bit (depending on your system. For some systems it's a 'who cares').

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw#usage) it would appear you need to use `mysql_fdw`. As you want to connect to a MySQL Database. [`postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/postgres-fdw.html) would be to connect to another PostgreSQL database.

The documentation for the `mysql_fdw` also includes examples on how to use it to setup a connection and update a table.